# Is this a ring counter ? What is its definition?

Tags: flipflop, counter

We can know the ring counter  like :0000 -> 1000 -> 0100 -> 0010 -> 0001,it  shifts the "1" bit.

Here is my schematic,the same as the schematic from the internet,and because my d-flip flop is active low,and Q=1 for set=reset=1 and set=0,reset=1,so as you can see,my output is not 0000,but 1000. I deliver a low signal at the white line ,0, to let first output become 1,and it does shift the "1" bit

So is it a ring counter? What is the definition of ring counter? Must it begin with 0000 and shift "1" bit from left to the right? or it is not necessary to begin with 0000 and just shift the bit,which is different from others, from the left to the right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter

Comment: No, it isn't a ring counter because it doesn't feed back the last output to the first input. Definition? [Wikipedia: ring counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter).

Comment: About the feedback,the last flip flop sent 0 to the first flipflop's input,D,and my first flipflop's input D is connect with the ground,D is always 0 ,so i think it is actually the same as feedback

Comment: NO. when R4 goes low, R1 should go high again. It should loop forever.

Comment: but i can set the reset to solve this problem

Comment: Reset is a different function.

Comment: so it can only be the shift register,but not the ring counter?